# OpenJPA PersistenceException in Liberty 8.5.5.3 Profile due to invalid URL

Tags: openjpa, websphere-liberty

I have just found an annoying mistake I made during the configuration of the DB2 JCC Properties in the "server.xml" of my Liberty Profile v8.5.5.3 which I wanted to share with you since it took me a long time searching the Web for helpful hints.

I configured a DB2 Datasource for JPA access in the "server.xml" using the Liberty Developer Tools in Eclipse Luna (Design tab): The "DB2 JCC Properties" are not sorted very clearly in my opinion. The required DB user name and password are not listed next to each other and made it hard for me to identify the correct properties. I unfortunately entered the DB user name in the field "Client User" instead of in "User" which is located nearly at the end of the list.
The thrown exception was:

```
<openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1595313 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1595313 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection could not be obtained for driver class "null" and URL "null".  You may have specified an invalid URL.
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newConnectException(DataSourceFactory.java:255)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:241)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:733)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94) ...    ... at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1176)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795) Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: [jcc][t4][10205][11234][4.18.60] Null userid is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 42815, Error Code = -4,461
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(kd.java:747)}
```

Comment: I'm sorry this error message is so poor. In the beta, there is a `<jpa ignoreDataSourceErrors="true">` option that can be used to make this easier to diagnose in jpa-2.0 (it is currently on by default in jpa-2.1). There are more details on this setting here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_jpa-2.0.html

Answer (score 0):

This exception indicates an incorrect connection URL: "You may have specified an invalid URL." but "A connection could not be obtained for driver class 'null' and URL 'null'" really pointed me in the wrong direction.

I recommend using the Source tab instead of the Design tab in the Liberty profile configuration tools and edit the XML entries manually to avoid wrong configuration values that may lead to confusion, e.g.

```
<server description="new server">
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>
<httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

<dataSource id="DB2Connection" jndiName="jdbc/DB2Connection">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DB2jdbc4libs"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc user="Administrator" databaseName="CUSTDB" password="{xor}password" portNumber="50000" serverName="dbserver.mycompany.com"/>
</dataSource>
<library id="DB2jdbc4libs">
        <fileset caseSensitive="true" dir="/opt/db2/V10.5/java" includes="db2jcc_license_cu.jar, db2jcc.jar"/>
</library>

<webApplication id="DynWebJPASample" location="DynWebJPASample.war" name="DynWebJPASample"/>
```